# Replace text Character Shift-JIS

Tags: vb.net

I have a problem with Shift Jis character. I used the following code but it is not working:

```
Imports System.IO
Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim line As String
        Using sr As StreamReader = New StreamReader("C:\2\File.txt", System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding(932))
            line = sr.ReadToEnd
            line.Replace("チ", "Chi")
        End Using
    End Sub
End Class
```

Thanks in advance. I hope you understand my problem.

Comment: You are not writing the line back into the file. You are only reading from it. Though Esko is correct as well, with `line = line.Replace("チ", "Chi")`. The string variable `line` holds the value you want but you need to write it back to the file. So what you need to do is, read file into a list, use replace on "チ" and then write list back into file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your only problem is that you are not storing the return value from the [replace-method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.replace(v=vs.110).aspx). So what I think you want is:

```
line = line.Replace("チ", "Chi")
```

If you want to replace the content back to the file, you can do it with something like this:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim filename As String = "C:\2\File.txt"
    Dim line As String
    Dim encoding As System.Text.Encoding = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding(932)

    ' You could replace the using-block with:
    ' line = File.ReadAllText(filename, encoding)
    Using sr As StreamReader = New StreamReader(filename, encoding)
        line = sr.ReadToEnd
        line.Replace("チ", "Chi")
    End Using

    File.WriteAllText(filename, line, encoding)
End Sub
```

Comment: Not working i think a i am forgetting  some code eg writeline maybe

Comment: Still Not Working &  not Chi in write file   This Word in  チ Hex 83 60 so

Comment: Thanks a lot i guess problem solve
 line=line.Replace("チ", "Chi") this is a problem