# Find and Replace Multiple Text

Tags: vb.net

Hello guys i need a tip how to used many txt find and replace codes ,i used many  codes but only  worked last code

```
    Dim filename As String = "C:\2\1.txt"
    Dim line As String
    Dim encoding As System.Text.Encoding = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding(932)
    line = My.Computer.FileSystem.ReadAllText("C:\2\1.txt", encoding)
        File.WriteAllText(filename, line.Replace("へ。", "C"), encoding)
        File.WriteAllText(filename, line.Replace("ら", "i"), encoding)
        File.WriteAllText(filename, line.Replace("だ", "G"), encoding)
```

so on ... only replace last code line

Thanks in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Replace text Character Shift-JIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48864950/replace-text-character-shift-jis)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using replace you need to update the actual variable.  For example

```
line = line.Replace("へ。", "C")
```

Otherwise you are just referring to a single instance.
Do this for all 3 replace statements, then a single call :

```
File.WriteAllText(filename, line, encoding)
```